# Toggling a blinking led ON & OFF

Tags: arduino-uno

I am trying to implement a toggle switch to turn blinking ON & OFF. However, the code only turns the led ON or OFF and that too unreliably. Can you help me understand why it isn't working?

```
   const int redLed = 10;
const int buttonPin = 2;
unsigned long newTime;
unsigned long oldTime = 0;
byte newButtonState;
byte oldButtonState = 0;
boolean ledState = false;
boolean blinkState = false;
boolean state = LOW;


void setup() {
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

  newButtonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  delay(100);


  // check if button state has changed
  if (newButtonState != oldButtonState) {
    // if button was pushed
    if (newButtonState == HIGH) {
      // check led state
      if (ledState == false) {
        ledState = true;
        blinkState = true;
      } else {
        ledState = false;
        blinkState = false;
      }
      if (ledState == true && blinkState == true) {
        newTime = millis();
        if (newTime - oldTime >= 250) {
          state = !state;
          oldTime = newTime;
        }
        digitalWrite(redLed, state);
      }
    }
  }
  oldButtonState = newButtonState;
}
```

Comment: Also it is not needed to add '== true' for comparing booleans, you can remove '== true' and instead of '== false' you put ! in front of the expression.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know that. I have seen a few sketches where they have used booleans without using "==" and I wondered if it's a different notation of if statements. But what if you are evaluating two booleans at once e.g. "if (ledState == true && blinkState == true)" , can you also write them without the == signs?

Comment: Yes than you can write `if (ledState && blinkState)`, if you want to write `if (ledState == true && blinkState == false)` you can write `if (ledState && !blinkState)`

Comment: Cool. Learnt something new. Thanks

Comment: I added an answer to show another improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why you would set `blinkState` together with `ledState`. I assume, that you want the button to toggle the blinking. 1 press --> LED is blinking, another press --> LED stops blinking, ...

I suggest to restructure your code. First separate input and output, meaning button check code and LED blink code. For blinking you already have a state variable named `blinkState`. So in your `loop()` function you first write

```
newTime = millis();
if(blinkState && newTime - oldTime >= 250){
    ledState = !ledState;
    oldTime = newTime;
}
```

That will toggle `ledState`, whenever `blinkState` is set, in intervals. Now we simply `digitalWrite()` that value out directly after that:

```
digitalWrite(redLed, ledState);
```

Now we need to handle the button. Your button if statements seem to be good, so we only need to change, whats inside the statements. There we simply negate the `blinkState` variable:

```
if (newButtonState != oldButtonState) {
    // if button was pushed
    if (newButtonState == HIGH) {
        blinkState = !blinkState;
    }
}
oldButtonState = newButtonState;
delay(100);
```

With this code the LED will stop changing and keep the state, that it had, when you pressed the button. If you want the LED to turn off at that point, you shoud add `ledState = false;` after negating `blinkState`.

Note, that this code doesn't need your `state` variable. 2 variables are enough for this. 1 for the current led state, 1 for the blinking state.

Also note, that using `delay()` is not the best way to debounce a button. It is an easy way, but it might not behave exactly, like you want to. If you want better debouncing, you can use the [Bounce2 library](https://github.com/thomasfredericks/Bounce2) from github. If you don't want to use a library for it, you can still learn about their ways to debounce in the Readme file.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear explanation. Also the suggestion to break the code makes it easier to follow.

Comment: I will try to follow this approach but all these state variables that are interdependent are new to me and at time confusing. I have also read about the concept of state machine and I wonder if it would be easier to code in such contexts

Comment: The state variables are not interdependent. You could see both variables to be of a different kind. While `ledState` directly describes the current output value of the LED pin, `blinkState` describes an action, which is a bit more abstract. Think of setting one foot before the other, which you could call one step. By changing a fictional state variable like `footstate` we could change, which foot is the front one, and thus do steps. Then the action "walking" is more abstract, since it is a succession of steps. walking describes the action of successively changing the front foot.

Comment: In this case a state variable will not be particular easier to implement. To be exactly: With this code you already have a state machine (as you handle state variables and act upon them). Just not one, that can easily be extended. You can change that to the more extendible version (on the web and on this side are many tutorials about FSMs), though that would be more to make it easier to extend the functionalities. With the current scope of the code you are fine with this structure.

Answer (score 2):

Note, this is not an answer, but I want to show some code examples based on the comment:

You can use as said in the comment:

- Remove '== true' in a boolean condition
- Replace '== false' by '!' in a boolean condition

You will get this:

```
  // check if button state has changed
  if (newButtonState != oldButtonState) {
    // if button was pushed
    if (newButtonState == HIGH) {
      // check led state
      if (!ledState) {
        ledState = true;
        blinkState = true;
      } else {
        ledState = false;
        blinkState = false;
      }
      if (ledState && blinkState) {
        newTime = millis();
        if (newTime - oldTime >= 250) {
          state = !state;
          oldTime = newTime;
        }
        digitalWrite(redLed, state);
      }
    }
  }
  oldButtonState = newButtonState;
}
```

About the following fragment:

```
  if (!ledState) {
    ledState = true;
    blinkState = true;
  } else {
    ledState = false;
    blinkState = false;
  }
```

Since you write `ledState` and `blinkState` in both clauses, and the condition is simple (so you don't need to put it in a temporary variable, you can replace this fragment by:

```
blinkState = !ledState;
ledState = !ledState;
```

Note you have to reverse the order as `blinkState` depends on `ledState`.

Answer (score 0):

You never set the `pinMode` of `buttonPin`.

Normally it defaults to `INPUT` if you don't manually specify anything, and I assume from your results that you don't have an external pullup or pulldown resistor.  Therefore you need to specify `pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);` and make sure that your switch or button connects the input pin to ground when activated (which means that "active" will be LOW).

Or, if you do have an external pullup or pulldown resistor then it sounds like it may not be wired corrcetly.

Comment: There is a pull down resistor in the circuit. I have added the pinMode but it still doesn't work. I suspect it has to do with the conditional statements. I tried changing the "if ledState == true && blinkState == true" to a while and it does start blinking but then it doesn't turn off. I really want to understand what's wrong with my logic here.

Answer (score 0):

Your blink code is only active

```
if (newButtonState != oldButtonState)
```

so it won't blink (by itself)

To toggle blinking, just change it e.g. like this

```
void loop() {
  bool newButtonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
  if (newButtonState != oldButtonState) { 
    // button state has changed
    delay(5);  // debounce
    oldButtonState = newButtonState; // run only once per button push
    if (newButtonState == HIGH) {
      // toggle blink state
      blinkState = ! blinkState;
    } 
  }

  if (blinkState) {
     // BlinkWithoutDelay
     unsigned long newTime = millis();
     if (newTime - oldTime >= 250) {
        state = !state;
        oldTime = newTime;
        digitalWrite(redLed, state);
     }
  } else {
     // no Blinking : just leave redLed as is
  }
}
```

Now please clean up the global variables: some are not required globally, some are not required at all.